# How to pass data to SectionList?

Tags: react-native

I am really confused as I don't understand how to pass an array to the SectionList. When I try this one everything is ok

```
 <SectionList
     renderItem={({item}) => <View><Text> title={item.title}</Text></View>}
      renderSectionHeader={({section}) => 
          <View><Text> title={section.key}</Text></View>}
          sections={[
               {data: [{title:123},{title:"aaa"}], key: "aaa"},
               data: [{title:333},{title:"bbbb"}], key: "bbb"},
               {data: [{title:123},{title:"aaa"}], key: "ccc"},
          ]}
          />
```

But if I try to use a function (as I understand it is totally the same), I got an error "props.sections.reduce is not a function". How to pass an array with function to the SectionList? Thanks

```
 sections={()=>[
        {data: [{title:123},{title:"aaa"}], key: "aaa"},
         data: [{title:333},{title:"bbbb"}], key: "bbb"},
         {data: [{title:123},{title:"aaa"}], key: "ccc"},
        ]}
  />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sections props require an array not a function. To use a function in sections props, this function must return an array. The array should contain a string key, and a data object. You can use many parameter in this object, for must information you can consult [this page](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/docs/sectionlist.html#sectionlist)

example:

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {

  selectionList = () => {
    return([
      {data: [{title:123},{title:"aaa"}], key: "aaa"},
      {data: [{title:333},{title:"bbbb"}], key: "bbb"},
      {data: [{title:123},{title:"aaa"}], key: "ccc"},
    ])
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <SectionList
          renderItem={({item}) => <View><Text> title={item.title}</Text></View>}
          renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <View><Text> title={section.key}</Text></View>}
          sections={this.selectionList()}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this one ()=>[1,23,4] - as I know, will return an array too, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong is the first you try to pass a function to section props, not a value.
to get value return from a function, you need to execute that function.
Example :

```
sections={(()=>[
         {data: [{title:123},{title:"aaa"}], key: "aaa"},
          {data: [{title:333},{title:"bbbb"}], key: "bbb"},
          {data: [{title:123},{title:"aaa"}], key: "ccc"},
          ]) () <<< execute function 
          }
         />
```